# Find special characters where i occurs the most

Tags: python, split

I have an assignment where I need to count the special characters in the string where it occurs the most.

The file I have contains three paragraphs with text and I need to compare them to each other to see where a set of characters occur and then count them where they occur the most.

Lines in the text:
`'I cannot go now. Give me lunch first at 12:15.'`

`After 13:100, he took a nap for until 13:15. Then in the late afternoon on 2018-11:30 at 16:30, he picked some bags and went to the palace. On the way, he felt hot so he sat under a tree to rest. Then, two hours later at 18:30, he got up to go but saw a man showing some magic tricks. He stopped to watch for an until 21:04.`

`When he reached the palace it was already after 21:03. The palace gates had been shut. So Haria had lost a golden chance because he had not learned the value of time on the 2018-13-01, a beautiful day.`

The code I have so far:

```
number_of_specials = 0
c = ['.', '.', ';', ':', '!', '?']
top = []
top_c1 = 0
top_c2 = 0
top_c3 = 0

with open(TEXT, "r") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        top.append(line.split("\n")) //to get the lines

if c in top[0]:
    top_c1 += 1
```

Not sure where to go from here, any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Could you some sample input and the expected output?

Comment: *"...where they occur the most."* Do you mean in which paragraph special characters appear the most?

Comment: All characters are "special". Do you mean the list of punctuation characters in your code?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Edited the text to include the lines. When I counted them I got the the top most should have 17 special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
c = ['.', '.', ';', ':', '!', '?']
top = ['asdd..,;;.:']
top_len = len(re.findall('['+''.join(c)+']',top[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store line and number of occurrences in tuple, and increment occurrences value by amount of particular character in string (line).

```
class Counter(object): # mutable object is needed to access it from tuple
    def __init__(self, start_value=0):
        self.value = start_value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

c = ['.', '.', ';', ':', '!', '?']
top = []

with open(TEXT, "r") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        top.append((line.split("\n"), Counter(0)))

for line, occurrences in top:
    for character in c:
        occurrences.value += line.count(character)
```